# VSTS / TFS Build only run NPM task when Git tag is committed and pushed

Tags: node.js, git, continuous-integration, azure-devops

On [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/process/conditions) it states you can set conditionals for a specific build task. For example to run the build on a specific version of a defined Git branch.

But is it also possible to make an conditional to make the VSTS to build the NPM package only if a commit contains a git-tag?

---

**Update 1:** The command `$ git describe` ([source](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)) seems like a possible part of the solution. This command takes the last commit hash and matches it to see if there were annotated tags. However, it doesn't equal it to a boolean value what we need in the custom condition of VSTS.

**Update 2:** Using npm [git-describe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/git-describe) you can return wether or not the latest commit has annotated tags. Example of a gulp task:

```
/** Example of a gulp task using git describe */
    var gulp                  = require('gulp');
    var {gitDescribeSync}     = require('git-describe');

    /**
     * @function
     * @name checkGitTag
     * @description Returns wether or not the latest commit has a tag
     * @returns {(String|null)} Git tag or null if no git tag exists on the commit
     */
    var checkGitTag = function() {

        var gitInfo = gitDescribeSync();

        // output the result to debug
        console.log(gitInfo.tag); 

        // gitInfo.tag seems to contain the logic needed
    };

    gulp.task('checkGitTag', checkGitTag);
    module.exports = checkGitTag;
```

Maybe by installing the NPM package on the build server and using a similar function would work. Going to test it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible to conditional run a task when the build commit contains tag(s).

But since there is no such predefined variable to record the tag for the build commit `$(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION)`, so you should add the steps (add a variable and a PowerShell task) to  check if there has tag(s) on the build commit. Detail step as below:

**1.** Add a variable (such as `result`) with the default value 0. And the variable is used for check if the build commit contains tag(s).

[image]

**2.** Then add a **PowerShell task** before the task which you want to conditional run, and the powershell script as below:

```
$tag=$(git tag --contains $(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION))
if($tag)
{
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result]1"
  echo "The build version $(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION) contains tag(s)"
}
else
{
  Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=result]0"
  echo "The build version $(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION) does not contain any tags"
}
```

**3.** Finally set custom condition for the task you want to run only when the commit contains tag as below:

```
and(succeeded(), eq(variables['result'], '1'))
```

[image]